# CSS background fixed and cover

Tags: css

I want to set a **fixed** background image that also **covers** the div but for some reason when I add **fixed** to the CSS, the image gets stretched way beyond the boundaries of the div.

These are 2 examples, one with **fixed** (*incorrect* dimensions) and the other with the *correct* dimensions but it's not fixed (it scrolls with page)

```css
#incorrect{
  min-height:100px;
  background: url('http://034.83e.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/entete_image.png') no-repeat fixed center/cover;
  }

#correct{
  min-height:100px;
  background: url('http://034.83e.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/entete_image.png') no-repeat center/cover;
  }
```

```html
<div id="incorrect"></div>

<br>

<div id="correct"></div>
```

How do you get both of these properties to work together? Are they incompatible?

EDIT: for some reason,[the fixed property is relative to the viewport and not to the element itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) The higher the screen, the bigger the image gets. Is there a turnaround?

Comment: Are you scrolling the div? or do you expect it to stay fixed when the viewport scrolls... remember that the div is going to scroll [with the page and cut the background off with it.](http://jsbin.com/qayayo/1/edit)

Comment: When you run the code snippet I added, you can see the fixed image doesn't scroll while the non-fixed one (correct dimensions) scrolls. I want the image to stay fixed when we scroll, but to cover the div the same way the CSS cover property works

Comment: About your edit, ``background-attachment: fixed`` tells specificaly to fix the background position to the viewport: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: Yes. That's what I am noticing. So is there a turnaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with pure CSS.

When you use `background-attachment: fixed;` it makes the image act the same as `position:fixed`.

**position:fixed** explained via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.

So what it's doing is taking your background image "out of the div" and sizing it relative to the viewport itself.  This is why it is "zooming" and "clipping" your background image.

You can work around this issue with JavaScript or jQuery.  Here is a snippet with your code used as an example:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('#incorrect').css('background-position', 'left ' + ((scrolledY)) + 'px');
});
```

```css
#incorrect{
  min-height:100px;
  background: url('http://034.83e.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/entete_image.png') no-repeat scroll center/cover;
  }

#correct{
  min-height:100px;
  background: url('http://034.83e.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/entete_image.png') no-repeat center/cover;
  }

div{margin-bottom:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="incorrect"></div>

<br>

<div id="correct"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
#incorrect{
  min-height:100px;
  background-image: url('http://034.83e.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/entete_image.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. This is just rephrasing and removing cover. http://jsfiddle.net/z46gapL8/2/